# How to preserve YAML content in Python dump

Tags: python, yaml

I am trying to load YAML file in Python using `ruamel.yaml`. My requirement is just to add few key/value in the YAML and dump it as is.

My input YAML file

```
---
# *REQUIRED*
person:
  name: 'John Doe'
  age: '30'
  city: 'Sample City'
  apis:
    - 'bigquery'
    - 'bigquerydatatransfer'
    - 'bigquerystorage'
    - 'bigtableadmin'
    - 'cloudbuild'
    - 'cloudkms'
preferences:
  theme: 'dark'
  language: en_US
  test: '77'
  shared_vpc_service: 'shared-vpc-admin'
  #################################################################

  #################################################################
  # *OPTIONAL* - Add Project to VPC Service Controls Security Perimeter
  # Default: True
  # If Set to False - Project will not be added to VPC Service Controls
  enable_vpc_svc_ctrls: True
  #################################################################
```

The output YAML file I am getting

```
---
# *REQUIRED*
person:
  name: John Doe
  age: '30'
  city: Sample City
  apis:
    - bigquery
    - bigquerydatatransfer
    - bigquerystorage
    - bigtableadmin
    - cloudbuild
    - cloudkms
preferences:
  theme: dark
  language: en_US
  test: '77'
  shared_vpc_service: shared-vpc-admin
  #################################################################

  #################################################################
  # *OPTIONAL* - Add Project to VPC Service Controls Security Perimeter
  # Default: True
  # If Set to False - Project will not be added to VPC Service Controls
  enable_vpc_svc_ctrls: true
  #################################################################
```

See, how the quotes from the values are gone. Also `enable_vpc_svc_ctrls: true` has become true from True.

This is the code snippet I have tried till now.

```
def add_quotes(value):
    # Add single quotes if the value is a string and not a boolean
    if isinstance(value, str) and not value.lower() == 'true':
        return f"{value}"
    # Convert boolean values to title case and keep them without quotes
    elif isinstance(value, bool):
        if str(value).lower() == 'true':
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return value


def process_yaml(node):
    if isinstance(node, dict):
        for key, value in node.items():
            node[key] = process_yaml(value)
    elif isinstance(node, list):
        for i, item in enumerate(node):
            node[i] = process_yaml(item)
    else:
        node = add_quotes(node)
    return node
```

I am tried explicit quotes on the node value but still not working

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make quotes part of your data structure and hope those will end up as quotes
in your YAML, that is never, ever, going to work. Those quotes will force alternative representations
of scalar string that can include
the quotes (normally escaped within double quoted scalars).

Your code snippet is a bit short on the actual processing of the YAML, but to preserve quotes
in a round-trip you have to explicitly indicate that you want that, and the same for the
initial end-of-directives marker ( `---` ). The quotes are superfluous, as is the end-of-directives marker (since you
have no directives), and you should IMO clean up your YAML, but that will mean a one time diff
to your original.

If you cannot clean up the inconsistent input mess you have, you
can however easily preserve the one and explicitly set the other using attributes on
your `YAML()` instance ( `.preserve_quotes` resp.
`.explicit_start`). The extra indent of your block style sequences can be set as well (`.indent`).

Although preserving boolean values with different casing is not possible, and the default output
for booleans is all lowercase, you can set the `.boolean_representation` attribute, which affects
all boolean representations:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """---
# *REQUIRED*
person:
  name: 'John Doe'
  age: '30'
  city: 'Sample City'
  apis:
    - 'bigquery'
    - 'bigquerydatatransfer'
    - 'bigquerystorage'
    - 'bigtableadmin'
    - 'cloudbuild'
    - 'cloudkms'
preferences:
  theme: 'dark'
  language: en_US
  test: '77'
  shared_vpc_service: 'shared-vpc-admin'
  #################################################################

  #################################################################
  # *OPTIONAL* - Add Project to VPC Service Controls Security Perimeter
  # Default: True
  # If Set to False - Project will not be added to VPC Service Controls
  enable_vpc_svc_ctrls: True
  #################################################################
"""

    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.explicit_start = True
yaml.boolean_representation = ['False', 'True']
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
# print(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
---
# *REQUIRED*
person:
  name: 'John Doe'
  age: '30'
  city: 'Sample City'
  apis:
    - 'bigquery'
    - 'bigquerydatatransfer'
    - 'bigquerystorage'
    - 'bigtableadmin'
    - 'cloudbuild'
    - 'cloudkms'
preferences:
  theme: 'dark'
  language: en_US
  test: '77'
  shared_vpc_service: 'shared-vpc-admin'
  #################################################################

  #################################################################
  # *OPTIONAL* - Add Project to VPC Service Controls Security Perimeter
  # Default: True
  # If Set to False - Project will not be added to VPC Service Controls
  enable_vpc_svc_ctrls: True
  #################################################################
```

I haven't diffed the output, but it looks close to your original input.